# i have been trying to make a clock in javascript but sometimes it shows up as undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, clock

js

the js at first it would work but when testing it i left the prompt undefined various times but time still showed up but after a couple of more times of leaving the prompt blank the tie showed undefined basically everthing in the get greeting would only come u as html as undefined which was strange because it has worked before

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = getGreeting();
    document.getElementById("welc").innerHTML = open();

};

var count = setInterval(function () {
    getGreeting()
}, 1000);

function getGreeting() {
    var dateNow = new Date();
    var time = dateNow.toTimeString();
    var hours = time.substring(0, 2);
    var today = dateNow.toDateString();
    var now = dateNow.toLocaleTimeString();
    var clock = document.getElementById("time");
    //var numhours = hours.parseInt();
    if (hours >= 12 && hours < 18) {
        return
        clock.textContent = "Good Afternoon, Welcome Time:" + today + " " + now;
        clock.innerText = "Good Afternoon, Welcome Time:" + today + " " + now;
    } else if (hours >= 18 && hours <= 23) {
        return
        clock.textContent = "Good Evening, Welcome Time : " + today + " " + now;
        clock.innerText = "Good Evening, Welcome Time : " + today + " " + now;
    } else if (hours >= 0 && hours < 12) {
        return
        clock.textContent = "Good Morning, Welcome Time:" + today + " " + now;
        clock.innerText = "Good Morning, Welcome Time:" + today + " " + now;
    }

}

function open() {
    var name = prompt("Hello User. What is your name?");
    if (name === '') {
        return "Hello User";
    } else if (name) {
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

html
all the is here is a menu with sub menus and a basic outline for a webpage 
i dont think the html would the problem

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="final.css">
<script type ="text/javascript"  src="final.js"></script>
<title>Final HTML/CSS Project-History of Major Tech Companies</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<h1>Home<h1>
</div>
<div id="nav">
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">ppgphb</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">ppgphb</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">ppgphb</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">myymmy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ymymmy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ymmyym</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ymmy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">mymyym</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">myymmy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ymymmy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ymmyym</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >ymmy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">mymyym</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#" >myymmy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ymymmy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ymmyym</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ymmy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">mymyym</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id ="footer"> <p id = "welc"></p><p id = "time"></p></div>
</body>


</html>
```

css here is the css it really has nothing to do with the issue but i added just incase

```
     body{
background-color:#DED4FF;
 }
 nav{
 margin-right:25px;
  }
 nav ul{

list-style-type:none;
position:relative;
display:inline;
 }
 nav ul li{

 position:relative;
 border:1px ouset #3B315C;
 color:#DED4FF;
 -color:#52447F;
 text-align:center;
 margin:5px;
 width:125px;
 padding:5px;
 margin-bottom:25px;
 box-shadow:0 1px 7px #CAC1E8;
 }
 nav li:visited{

 }
 nav ul ul{
 border:1px solid black;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 margin-left:1px;
 position:absolute;
 transition:display 8s;
 transition:display 8s;
 display:none;
 }
 nav ul li a{ 
 color:#DED4FF;
 text-decoration:none;
 display:block;
 }
 nav ul ul li a{
  transition:8s;
 }
}
nav ul ul li{
border:1px ouset #715FB5;
background-color:#A388FF;
margin:0px;
margin-left:90px;
box-shadow:0 1px 7px #413D63;
}
nav ul ul li a{
color:#6F6A7F;
}
nav ul ul ul li {

box-shadow:0 1px 7px ;
border:1px ouset #52447F;
background-color:#826DCC;
}
nav ul ul ul li a{
color:#52447F;
}
nav ul ul ul{
margin-right:18px;
float:none;
position:absolute;
transition:display 8s;
}
nav ul:after{
content:"";
clear:both;
display:block;
}
nav ul li:hover>ul{
display:block;
}
#header,#nav,#footer,#content{
height:100px;
}
#nav{
 border-right:1px solid black;
 text-align:center;
 width:145px;
 height:500px;
 float:left;
 }
 #content{
  float:right;
  }
  #footer{
   border-top:1px solid black;
    clear:both;
     }
    #header{
     border-bottom:1px solid black;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    }
```

Comment: It's better to use something like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for really long and multi-file examples like this.

Comment: There is no need for all that HTML and CSS, the OP should post a **minimal** test case that shows the problem. Often in developing the test case the issue will become clear and no post is required.

Comment: well the prob lies in the js file

Comment: @user2888333—note that the Date methods you are calling are implementation dependent, parsing them as if they are exactly the same in every browser and for every possible user preference setting is not a good idea (e.g. toDateString will almost ceratainly produce different results for US settings compared to almost any other setting).

Answer (score 0):

Well in the state that the code is in, it is impossible for it to have worked unless you added the return lately. The returns in the if statement short circuit the code.

```
if (hours >= 12 && hours < 18) {
    return  <-- anything after return will not run...
```

since you are not returning anything back, it will return undefined, which you are than shoving into the innerHTML. You should be returning the text.

```
if (hours >= 12 && hours < 18) {
    return "Good Afternoon, Welcome Time:" + today + " " + now;
}
```

Comment: wow really but it did before for a other project that only had the welcome message

Answer (score 0):

The clock should not work at all. In:

```
if (hours >= 12 && hours < 18) {
    return
    clock.textContent = "Good Afternoon, Welcome Time:" + today + " " + now;
    clock.innerText = "Good Afternoon, Welcome Time:" + today + " " + now;
```

automatic semi–colon insertion will insert a semi–colon after `return`, so the function returns *undefined* and does not execute the following two statements. You should have something like:

```
var clockString;
...
if (hours >= 12 && hours < 18) {
   clockString =  "Good Afternoon, Welcome Time:" + today + " " + now;
} else if (...) {
   ...
}

if (typeof clock.textContent == 'string') {
  clock.textContent = clockString;
} else if (typeof clock.innerText == 'string') {
  clock.innerText = clockString;
} else {
  clock.innerHTML == clockString
}
```

Comment: the bottom of your code im not exacetly sure for the reason for it can u expalin

Comment: Separate creation of the string from assigning as element content (which really should be a separate function), and fix the (unnecessary) return statement.